# Why isn't eDreams asking for a passport number?

Tags: air-travel, passports

I bought tickets from eDreams and this site didn't ask for a passport number only my name and bank account number so I could buy the ticket. Usually when I have booked from different sites, they always ask for a passport number. This brings up a question how will airport staff verify my identity when I want to check in for the flight?

Actually this isn't the only weird thing. When I checked my booked flight, I discovered that my return flight time has changed. I'm okay with the change, but shouldn't eDreams notify me about the change of the departure time? 
What should I do in this situation? Is everything okay?

Answer (score 5):

Staff won't verify your identity.  [Anyone with a matching name could arrive and check in for your flight.](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/dec/18/man-find-woman-same-name-ex-girlfriend-round-world-trip)  Fortunately, I've never heard of anyone being defrauded out of a ticket in this manner (how many people with a matching name will know that you have booked a flight so they can check in for it before you do)?

In fact, asking for passport details at booking has been quite rare until maybe ten years ago, at least in my experience.

To verify that you match the ticket, the airline will make sure that the name on your identification document matches the name on the booking, and the photograph on the identification document matches you.

As to the changed flight time, yes, perhaps your booking agent should notify you, but it's always safer to check directly with the airline.

Comment: I too fly regularly. For international bookings, it is common that the traveler's passport details are required at the time of purchase.

Comment: @David in my experience that is a recent development, and the airlines I fly with don't usually require passport details at the time of booking, but more often request them.  I also frequently fly different legs of the same booking using different passports, and nobody has ever blinked at this, nor questioned it.  There are far more airlines with whom I've never flown than those with whom I have, though, and I don't expect that all airlines would behave the same way.

Comment: @phoog, thanks for the expansion. My recent experience has been with Air New Zealand, Alaska, United, COPA, Amaszonas, and Norwegian, all booked from the US. And I've never left the passport number fields blank to test if the passport info field was a requirement or merely a request.

Comment: It varies a lot with both airline and third-party booking site having different policies.  https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26513/1264